# query optimization how to reduce planning time and execution time in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.4

query optimization how to reduce planning time and execution time in postgresql.
SQL Query :-

```
select s.id,state_name state, d.id no_districts,b.id no_blocks,v.id no_villages,district_name district,block_tehsil_name block,village_name village ,corr_vs,non_corr_vs,corr_gw,non_corr_gw,corr_sw,non_corr_sw 
from ref_state s left join ref_district d on d.ref_state_id=s.id 
left join ref_block_tehsil b on d.id=b.ref_district_id 
left join ref_village v on v.ref_block_tehsil_id=b.id 
left join (select ref_village_id ,coalesce(sum(tot_vs),0)-coalesce(sum(non_corr_vs),0) corr_vs,sum(non_corr_vs)non_corr_vs 
from (select ref_village_id,count(vs.id)tot_vs,(select count(id) from mi_census_village_schedule_validation vsv where vsv.ref_village_id=vs.ref_village_id)non_corr_vs from mi_census_village_schedule vs group by ref_village_id )vs1 group by ref_village_id ) vs on vs.ref_village_id=v.id 
left join(select ref_village_id ,coalesce(sum(tot_gw),0)- coalesce(sum(non_corr_gw),0) corr_gw,sum(non_corr_gw)non_corr_gw from (select ref_village_id,count(gws.id)tot_gw,(select count(id) from mi_census_ground_water_scheme_validation gwsv where gwsv.ref_village_id=gws.ref_village_id)non_corr_gw from mi_census_ground_water_scheme gws group by ref_village_id )gws1 group by ref_village_id ) gws on gws.ref_village_id=v.id 
left join (select ref_village_id,coalesce(sum(tot_sw),0)- coalesce(sum(non_corr_sw),0) corr_sw,sum(non_corr_sw)non_corr_sw from(select ref_village_id,count(sws.id)tot_sw,(select count(id) from mi_census_surface_water_scheme_validation swsv where swsv.ref_village_id=sws.ref_village_id)non_corr_sw from mi_census_surface_water_scheme sws group by ref_village_id )sws1 group by ref_village_id ) sws on sws.ref_village_id=v.id 
where s.id=30and d.id=21 and b.id=127 and v.id=632
```

Answer (score 3):

there are several techniques that can help improve the performance of SQL queries under workspaces. Follow the SQL best practices to ensure query optimization like

1. proper indexes,so that SQL queries can cause minimal table scans
2. Avoid using functions in predicates.
3. Avoid using wildcard (%) at the beginning of a predicate.
4. Avoid unnecessary columns in SELECT clause.
5. Use inner join, instead of outer join if possible. -- You have used multiple left join in your above query which also impact your query.
6. DISTINCT and UNION should be used only if it is necessary.
7. use of order by clause when sorted result set is required.Be aware of the performance impact of adding the ORDER BY clause, as the database needs to sort the result set, resulting in one of the most expensive operations in SQL execution

Comment: Thank you for your response ,this is very large query ,what method i can use for optimization?

Comment: @Priyanka tripathi can you edit your question with table structure  with dummy dataset as well as expected output.